# if/else depending on whether input is a number

Tags: kotlin, if-statement

I want to write a print age program using if/else.

If given an non-numeric input then, it should print "sorry numeric value expected."

This is what I have so far:

```
 import java.util.*
 //import javax.print.attribute.IntegerSyntax
 fun main(agrs : Array<String>) {
      //var value1  = 11.0fe is $age")
     val input = Scanner(System.`in`)
           println("enter your Age ")
      val a = input.nextInt()
           println("your age is : " + a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun main() {
    val age = readLine()?.toIntOrNull()
    if (age == null)
        print("Please enter a valid age")
    else
        print("Your age is $age")
}
```

Comment: You might want to look up what toIntOrNull does.

Comment: `toIntOrNull` try to parse a String to Int if not catch the exception and throw null. Can you expand on the comment? @Morinator

Comment: Yes. It just appeared to me that he's new to programming and wanted to encourage him to look up new library-stuff you don't encounter often.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
fun main() {
    print("enter your Age: ")
    val age = readLine()?.toIntOrNull()
    if (age == null) {
        println("sorry numeric value expected")
    } else {
        println("your age is: $age")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @TomerShetah. I've been here for 9 years . But you're right, I should have included an explanation, rather than just code. However, considering the quality of the question, it's difficult to know what to explain without covering the basics of the language. The code is so simple it almost speaks for itself, here.